# VB.NET TableAdapter not defined

Tags: vb.net, datatableadapters

I'm sure this must be an easy fix, but I haven't been able to see my error. This code worked previously. I'm currently using VS 2019. I'm receiving an error that my tableadapter is not defined.

```
Dim mbtAdapter As New DataSet1TableAdapters.amongthehiddenTableAdapter
Dim mbtDataTable As DataSet1.amongthehiddenDataTable = Nothing
mbtDataTable = mbtAdapter.GetDataByQuestion(question)
```

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'DataSet1TableAdapters.amongthehiddenTableAdapter' is not defined.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

[dataset1.xsd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxnHN.png)

[tableadapter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rabz1.png)

--- update 7/31/20 ---
[Expanded dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRs9C.png)

[Dataset properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtDoM.png)

[Hover - namespace message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWG9K.png)

Comment: Does that type exist? Have you actually looked?

Comment: @Dionna try adding this Using dt As New DataTable

Answer (score 0):

Look for the presence of this in your Solution Explorer:

[image]

Single click it and check your properties window looks like this:

[image]

Double click it and look for something like this:

[image]

If you got to here, let me know and I'll suggest some more stuff

Comment: Thanks for replying!
I've added screenshots to my summary of the problem above. Everything looks okay to me.

Comment: Please also show a screenshot of the properties window? Your DataSet doesn't look exactly like mine in that it doesn't have any child nodes on the solution explorer - can you click "show all files" and make another screenshot? Also if you click the line with the error does a   appear in the line numbers? Does clicking it offer to import a namespace?

Comment: I added screenshots of the expanded dataset and the properties window.
There is no lightbulb when I click the line. There is a message when I hover on the line. I've added the screenshot above as well.
Thanks again for taking time to help!

Comment: I do have a work-around, so there is no rush on this. I would like to figure out what I have wrong in my code though.